# How to encode and decode URL parameter in php

Tags: php

I have encoded url parameter in php using 'base64_encode' and 'hash' like this,

http://localhost:81/url_encrypt/page-2.php?param=STZ6YmdBRVRJMjRsSVJtUndxblRjQT09

Is it safe or it can be cracked easily???

If it can be cracked, then what will be param=????
and how it will be cracked?

Comment: yes, it can be cracked easily. You should better use encrypted with private key, like jwt token

Comment: `hash` is, by definition, cannot be reversed if the source has enough entropy.

Comment: If that is really containing a hash, how on earth do you get access to the original un hashed data????

Comment: I am using secret key to decrypt. Still this is unsafe???

Comment: Hashing and encryption are not the same thing - can you decide which one you're using please?

Comment: You can't regenerate the same hash. How do you verify the hash is correct or not? You will need some function which works similar to `password_verify()`.

Comment: it is hash, openssl_encrypt, base64_encode that I am using together.

Comment: Why would you hash something and then encrypt it?

Comment: I don't want to reveal that algo. If it can be cracked, crack it.
I have a function that can regenerate original string from url param.

Comment: No one's asking you to reveal your super-secret algorithm, just *why* you're performing these steps. What are you actually trying to achieve? Passing encrypted data via a query string? Or passing a hash? There's no reason to combine those two concepts, they are each for solving a different problem.

Comment: Also, if we don't know your key, it is difficult to decrypt but someone can brute force maybe.

Comment: My purpose is to don't share url actual parameter.

Comment: So just pass a unique ID that maps to the true value in a database and look it up yourself later. Why risk it being cracked at all?

Comment: – iainn , thanks,
plz give a little bit of idea, how to achieve that.

Comment: and my parameter value is not so sensitive, i want to unable a user so that he can't experiment with consecutive values like index.php?imp_id=111, (he may try 112, 113, 114 and so on). that is it.

Comment: I am trying this, 
window.onload=function(){

history.replaceState(window.location.href, null, window.location.pathname);
}
its is working but when page is refreshed hidden param are lost.